# Template ref do not trigger watchers

Tags: vue.js, watch

I'm facing a weird issue about `watchers` and `template refs`.

I have the following component in which I used an `slot`.

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="state.widgetClasses"
    ref="widgetElement"
  >
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

The content in the `<slot />`  could be large and overflow the component, so I need to add behavior using `widgetClasses`. That property is being created using `reactive` as follow:

```js
const state = reactive<State>({
  'widgetClasses': '',
  ...
});
```

The `overflowed` state could be detected using `scrollHeigth` and `scrollClient` provided by the ref `widgetElement`, I used the following watchers to check if `overflowed`.

```js
watch(
  () => widgetElement.value?.scrollHeigth,
  () => checkOverflow(),
  { 'flush': 'post' }
);
```

and

```js
watchEffect(
  () => checkOverflow(),
  { 'flush': 'post' }
);
```

Both do not work, they only be triggered when the component is `mounted` (`widgetElement` is not `undefined`) and do not detect when `widgetElement.vale.scrollHeigth` changes after mounted.

Comment: There's a typo in scrollHeigth. If it's not your actual code then please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem . Also DOM elements are not reactive, so you can't watch their properties. This needs to be done in `scroll` listener

Comment: `ref`s are also not reactive - they can't be watched.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank you for answer, I proceed to use `MutationObserver` and I can trigger side effect any time the content in the `<slot />` changes.

Comment: @EstusFlask it is the actual code, thank you for your answer. I would like to know why DOM elements (and its properties) are not reactive.

Comment: Because they aren't made reactive by the framework and by you, and it would be incredibly costly to do this, performance-wise. When you have to deal with raw DOM like in this case, this is done the same way as in regular JS. Yes, MutationObserver is the way.